# How to format date in c# for eg(Wed, 04/28/2013)

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I want to format the date like this Wed, 04/28/2013.Anyone knows a simple code to format the date like this?

Comment: Change it to that format, or change it from that format?

Comment: This question is repeated
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=format+date+c%23

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to `ToString` to ensure that `/` as date separator is used since it would normally be replaced with the current culture's date separator:

```
string date = dt.ToString("ddd, MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/elZhXe)

Comment: actually, it should replace the separator if other language was set. Should I take out the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to apply this behavior?

Comment: @user335160: If you want to use the current culture's date separator(e.g. `.` in germany) you just have to remove the second parameter or pass `null`.

Comment: Tim Schmelter-thank you very much.

Comment: @user335160: One note: if you want to mix both, e.g. the current culture's day-name but the `/` as date separator you have to concat both: `dt.ToString("ddd") + dt.ToString(", MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 0):

Use a string ;)
Here's an example for you:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Answer (score 0):

insert `DatetimePicker`

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.toString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Second option Create DateTime Variable

```
DateTime da=new DateTime();
```

and where you want to use call like this

```
da.DateTime.Now();
```

Hope You Liked it